# Error: "There is no current event loop in thread" when used concurrent.futures with HTMLSession

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-multiprocessing, concurrent.futures, python-requests-html

Can you help me find a bug in my code ?

I'm trying to speed up web scraping URLs gathered by using `googlesearch.search`.

*Note!

This seems similiar issue as it was described in this post:

[Concurrent.futures + requests_html's render() = "There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0'."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148076/concurrent-futures-requests-htmls-render-there-is-no-current-event-loop)

But after attempting to implement it the way it was described there, I still can't get rid of my issue.

Here's my original code so far:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import multiprocessing as mp
import concurrent.futures
from googlesearch import search

#get 20 urls for "funny cats"
def getURLs():
    urls = list(search("funny cats", tld='com', num=20, stop=20, pause=2))
    return urls

# divide list of 20 urls into list of 4 lists x 5 url
# each sub-list will be processed on one processor (I have 4 cores) 
def fillContainer(some_iterable):
    my_gen = iter(some_iterable)
    cores = mp.cpu_count()
    container = [ [] for n in range(cores) ]
    while True:
        for a in container:
            try:
                a.append(next(my_gen))
            except StopIteration:
                return container

def processURL(urls):
    with HTMLSession() as session:
        for u in urls:
            try:
                response = session.get(u)
                response.raise_for_status()
                response.html.render()
                # plus some regex to process html, but that's not the point
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"ERROR !!! {e} , accessing URL: {u} , Movinh on ...")

def main():
    URLs = getURLs()
    container = fillContainer(URLs)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(processURL, url) for url in container]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get the :

`There is no current event loop in thread 'ThreadPoolExecutor'`

Error for each URL I try to proces using my `processURL()` function. I also tried using: `executor.map(processURL, URLs)`  but with no success.

Thank you for your help.

#EDIT #1

It seems that there's a problem with line: `response.html.render()` ,

however I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: did you solve it ?

Comment: @user2396640 No. I did some workaround and forgot about it.